# Запуск скриптов на php через ajax и остановка через ajax

Tags: php, ajax, запуск

Есть задача не могу ее решить. 
А именно:
Есть скрипт на пхп который получить через ajax пост запрос на старт выполнения. Скрипт идет в базу данных берет значение и начинает выполнять. По окончанию берет следующее и так далее. Суть в том что этот скрипт может выполнятся не один час. И есть необходимость останавливать его.

Для этого реализовал в базе данных значение статус 1 и статус 0 Когда приходит запрос на выполнения скрипта мы ставим значение 1 и начинаем работать. После обработки одного значения из базы данных мы проверяем что у нас записано в статусе и либо берем новое значение либо выходим из цикла.

Сделана вторая кнопка которая через ajax отправляет запрос на тот же скрипт только с пост значением stop, Скрипт получив запрос меняет в базе статус с 1 на 0 и работа завершается.

Но проблема в том что когда я делаю ajax запрос на старт, пока ajax не получить ответ от скрипта он не отправляет запрос на остановку. То есть нажатие на кнопку стоп не происходит. 
Подскажите как это можно реализовать, что я делаю не так?

```
$(document).ready (function (){
                $("#start").bind("click", function (){
                    $.ajax ({
                        url: 'index.php',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: 'start=1',
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: finals
                    });
                });
                $("#stop").bind("click", function (){
                    $.ajax ({
                        url: 'index.php',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: 'stop=1',
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: finals2
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: Сделайте по-другому. Пусть фоновый скрипт всегда работает. Он при каждом цикле должен лезть в базу данных и проверять некоторую строку с состоянием. Если состояние 1 - скрипт выполняет полезную работу. Если состояние 0 - скрипт с паузой ожидает другого состояния.

Comment: не совсем понимаю как это реализовать. 
Javascript а именно ajax делает только одно, он отправляет запрос на php скрипт который начинает колотить. И он должен начинать работу именно после нажатия на кнопку, поскольку там заполняется форма с входными данными, нужными для выполнения php скрипта. 

Я так понимаю что проблема заключается в том что сам php и апач не позволяет выполнять параллельно 2 скрипта одному пользователю. 
Направьте меня на путь истинный, с javsscript я не знаком, смог только написать ajax запрос.

Comment: Если скрипт выполняется долго, то лучший выход - это job. Запускаете скрипт как демон, а он лезет в базу данных и вытаскивает из очереди задания на обработку

Comment: Согласен с ArchDemon, можно доверить периодический запуск php скрипта планировщику заданий crontab, но ограничить выполнение этого скрипта по времени, чтобы не было ситуации, когда одновременно выполняются несколько копий. Ajax-ом влиять только на состояние статуса в базе данных.

Comment: Демон нужен. Демону можно сигнал слать на старт и на стоп - там много методов. Самое топовое это очередь типа рэбита. А пхп в обычном понимании только с костылями.

Answer (score 0):

в рамках использования php вы все делаете правильно.
ваша проблема решается созданием отдельного php файла, который запускает php скрипт
я так запускал web-socket сервер

```
<?php
exec('php your.php > your.log');
```

Этот код будет запускать скрипт в фоновом режиме. - общаться с ним можете через записи в базе данных, через записи в файл или посредством вебсокетов - вариантов много

Comment: подскажите где можно почитать про такую реализацию ? 
Поскольку пишу маленький модуль для opencart там есть свои особенности реализации. Хочу изучить и придумать как это реализовать в этой системе. 

Как я понимаю нужно сделать скрипт который будет отдавать приказ выполнять работу. А ajax возвращать  значение что процес запущен?

Comment: а просто запускайте  ajaxом выше указанный код - этот код будет запускать ваш скрипт(запуск php из консоли - и перенаправление вывода в файл - для для LINUX подойдет) а если хотите остановить скрипт - запускайте аяксом файл пхп, который будет делать запись в базу (запись в таблицу, которую считывает ваш скрипт на наличе продолжить скрипт или нет) В вашем скрипте должен быть цикл - при начале каждого цикла идет проверка записи в базу если она есть цикл прекращает работу и скрипт прекращается - он записывает в базу на каком моенте он остановился. Скрипт завершается.